# Using $sce.trustAsResourceUrl in Angular routeProvider?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

for my routing, I am using static templates that come from an external source. However, I keep getting the insecureUrl error from Angular. One solution apparently is to have it with the `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl` wrapped around it. Now, I am trying to do it the following way:

```
myapp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider, $sce) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller : 'ProductListController',
            templateUrl : $sce.trustAsResourceUrl([my_external_template]),
            reloadOnSearch: false
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo : '/' });
}]);
```

However, I get the injector error. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
myapp.config(['$routeProvider', '$sce', function($routeProvider, $sce) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller : 'ProductListController',
            templateUrl : $sce.trustAsResourceUrl([my_external_template]),
            reloadOnSearch: false
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo : '/' });
}]);
```

Since you are manually doing minsafe syntax you need to add $sce to the string part of the injection array (ideally just don't do the minsafe syntax use a plugin to add that before uglification in your build process)

Comment: Okay so doing this, I get the Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error. Any idea why?

Comment: Be sure you are using regular angular.js while developing to get the best error messages not angular.min.js, copy and paste the entire error  Would also help to copy/paste your updated code in the question to be sure nothing was missed in the changes.

Comment: Thanks, I got a more understandable error now: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $sce. Im still confused though, as the $sce module works rights in another controller :/

Comment: Ah right so since you're in a config block here you're limited on what you can inject, see the bottom of the angularJS providers page.  Reading what you're trying to do more closely too using $sce for the templateUrl wouldn't be appropriate anyhow you might want it for the template but the URL is just meant to point to another file or template from templateCache to load, $sce is just for content being bound into the view typically.  In config you could access the $sceProvider, but config is meant as the time you can configure all providers before they are used in run() or controllers etc.

Comment: See the table at the bottom here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Basically when angular bootstraps it executes all the config blocks to setup any providers before they are used, then it executes all of the run block functions, then it starts parsing the html (see html compiler in docs) for directives to execute their link functions etc.

Comment: Ultimately what you can do is load whatever string you want to $sce trust in the controller for this route definition and then use $sce service on the string and assign the result to a property on the scope or as a property of the controller then bind it into the view with a simple template

Comment: Thanks a lot for those comments. However, I will be honest, Im probably not smart enough to understand the inner workings of Angular. Could you write an answer on how I can use trustAsResourceUrl in my route config?

Comment: Sorry I'm just not really understanding the use case, does this relate to your problem? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider if not can you elaborate a bit more on why you need to use that function (I'm not familiar with it to be honest)  I can show how you would inject $sce in the ProductListController, then use it in there and have a template that binds to a property of that controller (and the property having been passed through $sce.trustAsHTML or whatever) but might be barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/DKm0DKDzrYJ7A3Ooqdtm/ <-- this is essentially what I was thinking but instead of ng-src you would just have your template be something like `<div>{{source}}</div>` or perhaps `<div ng-bind-html="source"></div>` but so long as you are injecting the $sce into the ProductListController instead of the config block itself you shouldn't have a problem.  There is no way to really get a instance of $sce yet in config because the thing that makes the $sce object for the injector  (called the $sceProvider) can be changed in any config block.